# Error in template generated by Qt in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2019

So I've been trying to play around with Qt in Visual Studio. However, when I create a GUI application, the automatically generated template already contains a compiler error, namely:

> Error (active) E1696   cannot open source file "ui_QtGuiApplication1.h"    QtGuiApplication1   E:\visual_studio_projects\gui_test\QtGuiApplication1\QtGuiApplication1.h    4

I couldn't locate the ui_QtGuiApplication1.h header anywhere in the solution.
Removing the include statement results in the Ui class not being found. As far as I can tell, the Ui class is supposed to be located in ui_QtGuiApplication1.h.

QtGuiApplication1.h:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_QtGuiApplication1.h"

class QtGuiApplication1 : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::QtGuiApplication1Class ui;
};
```

QtGuiApplication1.cpp:

```
QtGuiApplication1::QtGuiApplication1(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**  The ui_QtGuiApplication1.h was generated automatically by uic after the corresponding .ui file is saved in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `#include "ui_QtGuiApplication1.h` is generated from your "QtGuiApplication1.ui" Designer file. Seems, that you didn't call the [User Interface Compiler Tool (uic)](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/uic.html).